# Http connection graphaware

Tags: php, neo4j, graphaware

So, this is the think I have downloaded Neo4j community edition to a cloud server running ubuntu server 15.10, not problem still there and have downloaded, installed, run and configure for remote access successfully Neo4j, so no problem still. I think that I downloaded well graphaware, since the folders and files all have been created, but when I introduce this code

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\ClientBuilder;

$client = ClientBuilder::create()
->addConnection('default', 'http://neo4j:password@localhost:7474')
->addConnection('bolt', 'bolt://neo4j:password@localhost:7687') 
->build();
```

Is when everything go to wrongs, not only the connection is not created but it turn to an error where the website is not loaded and not even the error is show, so I suspect that is a problem with my graphaware installation or configuration. I have obviously changed password to my real password, try copying the hole vendor folder to my "public HTML" folder, deleting that copy, replacing localhost with my server ip, everything. Until now the most close that I have reach to find the problem's source it's that when I quote just the client builder, leaving the code like this:

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\ClientBuilder;
/*
$client = ClientBuilder::create()
->addConnection('default', 'http://neo4j:password@localhost:7474')
->addConnection('bolt', 'bolt://neo4j:password@localhost:7687') 
->build();
*/
```

Then everything work.

Is there any problem with my code or can somebody guide me to establish the connection correctly??

If so, thanks very much.

Comment: Just a p.d., when I try to enter Neo4j by the 7684 bolt port I get this issue "not a WebSocket handshake request: missing upgrade" don't know if will have something related